# How to test directive, that has parent directive defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a util for my app - [batch-checkbox-util.js](https://gist.github.com/jeserkin/0c50e303c648132e9635) and would like to test it now.

I've written test, that is at the same link, but for some reason during test run, it fails and says, that controller isn't available. Controller, that is used by child directvie from parent directive.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to try this in your `compileElement` function:             `angular.element(document.body).append(element);`

Comment: @JamesKleeh Didn't help. Have you tried it out? Did it work in your case? I tried your suggestion before `scope.$digest()`, but after `$compile` call. I'm not sure about the `scope` thou. In some article I've seen, that you create subscope (`$rootScope.$new()`), but you call digest on the parent scope (i.e. `$rootScope`). Can that be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the cause and therefore the solution, but to solve the issue at hand I had to make parent directive optional `?^`. Maybe during tests it doesn't have enough time to load it.

Again not sure about the reason and due to the change, now directive must either check the controller presence or throw error to inform, that controller is not available at the moment.